# Podspec: Prefix import not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

My project is building ok. When I run `pod spec lint` I receive following error:

```
 - ERROR | [MyApp/Core] [xcodebuild]  Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/Pods-MyApp-prefix.pch:6:9: fatal error: 'MyConstants.h' file not found
```

It's worth noticing the location of constants file: `Project/Classes/MyConstants.h`. Here is my `podspec`:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = "AppName"
  spec.version      = "1.0"
  spec.summary      = "blah blah"
  spec.homepage     = "http://company.com/"
  spec.license      = 'Apache 2.0'
  spec.author       = { "me" => "me@company.com" }
  spec.source       = { :git => 'ssh://path', :tag => '1.0'}

  spec.requires_arc = true
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'
  spec.frameworks   = ['Foundation', 'UIKit', 'CoreGraphics', 'QuartzCore']

  spec.source_files = 'Classes/**.*', 'Classes/ViewControllers/**.*', 'Classes/Views/**.*'

  spec.prefix_header_contents = '#import "MyConstants.h"'

  spec.subspec 'Core' do |cs|
    cs.dependency 'libextobjc', '~> 0.4'
  end

end
```

I've also tried to exchange line:

```
spec.prefix_header_contents = '#import "MyConstants.h"'
```

with:

```
spec.prefix_header_file = 'MyApp/MyApp-Prefix.pch'
```

But the result is the same. What should I do to enable prefix to see source code?

--- EDIT ---

I've ended with refactoring all my source files. I've imported the classes which were needed manually, without using prefix. As so, this question was no longer important for me.

Comment: You should not rely on the `pch` since in the latest Xcode this is no longer create by default. Just include the `MyConstants.h` in every `.m` that needs it.

Comment: This is not the solution, rather a workaround. I want to have `pch` and I don't have time to refactor whole app not to use it.

Comment: It's bad design to be deepened on the `pch` file, but that is you option. You library that you want to add the cocoa pods should be able to work in a project without a `pch` file.

Comment: @rckoenes I have a global warning macro there I wish to use. It is my choice as you wrote. I am fully aware of it. The fact there is a possibility to add a `pch` file means, that my library can use it. That doesn't help to solve my issue and please let's not dive into the offtopic.

Comment: You should add you Pod name to the import, like: `#import <AppName/MyConstants.h> `

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for the answer, but I still get an error: `- ERROR | [AppName/Core] [xcodebuild]  Target Support Files/Pods-AppName/Pods-AppName-prefix.pch:6:9: fatal error: 'AppName/MyConstants.h' file not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue. In the end I added `ss.public_header_files` in my `subspec`. Its more a work around which worked for me (I wouldnt call it a solution). according to docs:

```
public_header_files

 A list of file patterns that should be used as public headers.    
These are the headers that will be exposed to the user’s project
and from which documentation will be generated. If no public
headers are   specified then all the headers are considered public.
```

Maybe its not entirely accurate.

**Edit**
My solution wasn't entirely correct. When I run the validation with `pod lib lint` it was successfully builded when I validate it with `spec` option I received the same error again.I ended up writing the question to cocaoPods team. [.pch wont recognise included files](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3318)

Comment: I've ended with importing the prefix in places, where it's needed. Costed me some time to refactor, but well ;).

Comment: Vive can you please edit your question and write how did you solve it?

Comment: Sure, done. As I've said I've just bypassed the issue. I've checked your answer as the real one, because this seems closest to resolving the issue. If you ever get answer from CocoaPods team, please inform me too - it would be useful in different projects.

Answer (score 0):

With `spec.prefix_header_contents = '#import "MyConstants.h"'`
you specified a code-line to insert in `.pch` file, created by `pod` during the installation process. If you got this error, it is because the file `MyConstants.h` was missing.

**EDIT**
If your `MyConstants.h` file is a main project source, you cannot access it from a `Pod`.

Comment: The problem is that it is not missing! I understand what the error says. I don't know how to make cocoapods see that header. I even wrote the location of the file in my question and you can notice, that it is imported. In previous commit I can see the file after installing from podfile in different project.

Comment: You have to include the `.h` file into your `s.source_files`. You cannot access to main project files from a `pod`

Comment: `spec.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'` imports the .h file. It is a part of module project ofc.

Comment: I did the same thing in my `podspec` file and it works. Trying to do a `pod install` which are the files that cocoapods downloaded? I think that there is an error in the `podspec` about the source_file property. Maybe the folders hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I fail at `pod spec lint`. I don't even do pod install, because the spec is not pushed to my private cocoapods. Yes, you're right with source_file property, I've discovered moment ago the thing with `Classes/**.*` instead of `Classes/**/*`, however still the update fails :/

Comment: There is also the folder `Project` in your repository? If yes, try modifying the source_file string inserting the prefix `Project/Classes/**.*`

Comment: It is included in source_file path :/. And my previous version (wich didn't include prefix but did include MyConstants.{h,m} was working ok. I turned on different project, typed pod install with previous version and I can see MyConstants.{h,m} in my Pods subproject. Can you paste your working podspec with prefix please?

Comment: Taking a look at the documentation, I don't know if `Classes/**.*` can be the right string you have to type. I think that it will not accept the * for the extensions (it is only my opinion). Try typing the exact extension file like you did ( `{h,m}`). In fact, I saw other podspec files and all of those use the `{h,m}` instead of `*`

Comment: Tried with {h,m}, same result == still errror not found.